# Programmatically make HTTP requests through proxies with Python

Tags: python, http, proxy

How do I use Python to make an HTTP request through a proxy?

What do I need to do to the following code?

```
urllib.urlopen('http://www.google.com')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `urlopen` function supports proxies.  Try something like this:

```
urllib.urlopen(your_url, proxies = {"http" : "http://192.168.0.1:80"})
```

Comment: Well, since those sites are not proxy servers you would require a very different solution.  Technically a proxy server is a machine on your network that relays all internet traffic.

Comment: @AndrewHare A proxy server doesn't have to be on your local network at all. Can be on your local machine, local network, remote computer, wherever.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at [PycURL](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/). I use cURL a lot in PHP and i love it. Though there is probably a neat way to do this currently in Python.