# Python HTTP request through proxy working, but HTTPS request not working

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have some code to request a URL external to my organisation's network:

```
proxy_string = 'http://proxyIP:proxyport'
s = requests.Session()
s.trust_env=False
s.proxies = {"http": proxy_string , "https": proxy_string}
s.auth = HTTPProxyAuth("ad\user","password")
url = "http://canoeracing.org.uk/marathon/results/results2017.html"

r = s.get(url)
r.status_code
tree = html.fromstring(r.content)
r.content
```

This works fine if the URL is an HTTP (like the one above), but not if it's an HTTPS URL (so change `url` to `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894168/programmatically-make-http-requests-through-proxies-with-python`). Things I've tried:

- Changing the `HTTPS_Proxy` in the command line
- Changing `proxy_string` to `https://...`

I know there's some similar questions to this, but I couldn't find any that had had this specific problem of HTTP requests working through a proxy but HTTP requests not.

Comment: Are you sure your proxy forward https too ?

Comment: What d'you mean by this?

Comment: In other words, if you configure a browser to use that proxy for HTTPS, does it work?

Comment: How would I go about configuring a browser to use my proxy details?